# How to add button in gallery

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

My application contains some pictures in a gallery.  I want to add a button that changes with respective selected image.  I'm in the early stages.  How can I add this code in my project.

The code is below:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class GalleryView extends Activity {
Integer[] pics = {
    R.drawable.antartica1,
    R.drawable.antartica2,
    R.drawable.antartica3,
    R.drawable.antartica4,
    R.drawable.antartica5,
    R.drawable.antartica6,
    R.drawable.antartica7,
    R.drawable.antartica8,
    R.drawable.antartica9,
    R.drawable.antartica10
   };
  ImageView imageView;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

Gallery ga = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.Gallery01);
ga.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
ga.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                "You have selected picture " + (arg2+1) + " of Antartica", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        imageView.setImageResource(pics[arg2]);

    }

});

}


public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context ctx;
int imageBackground;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    ctx = c;
    TypedArray ta = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
    imageBackground = ta.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 1);
    ta.recycle();
}

public int getCount() {

    return pics.length;
}

public Object getItem(int arg0) {

    return arg0;
}

public long getItemId(int arg0) {

    return arg0;
}

public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(ctx);
    iv.setImageResource(pics[arg0]);
    iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    iv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150,120));
    iv.setBackgroundResource(imageBackground);
    return iv;
}

}
}
```

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >

<Gallery 
android:id="@+id/Gallery01" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Gallery>
<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/ImageView01" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>


 </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you well, but if you want the `ImageView`'s image to be set when gallery item is selected you should use `setOnItemSelectedListener` like this

```
 ga.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            imageView01.setImageBitmap(pics[position});
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
    });
```